# jpms + cdi (weld): WELD-ENV-000033: Invalid bean archive scanning result - found multiple results with the same reference

Tags: java, cdi, weld, java-platform-module-system

I'm new to jpms and try to setup a simple environment (java 19, graalvm, latest maven) to start a project with jpms + cdi (weld). My problem is: As soon as I create a(n even empty) `module-info.java` in my project weld produces an exception like below for a primitive cdi test. As soon as I remove `module-info.java` it disappears again and the test succeeds.

I found one potential candidate for the "multiple results" from the exception. There is a `beans.xml` in `src/main/resources/META-INF` and in `src/test/resources/META-INF` but as I said it is no problem if I remove `module-info.java` from `src/main/java`. I also tried with only one `beans.xml` in both locations but that did not change the behaviour.

I could not find any hint for the reason of my problem. So any ideas are appreciated.

Here comes the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: WELD-ENV-000033: Invalid bean archive scanning result - found multiple results with the same reference: ...\jpms\common\target\test-classes

    at org.jboss.weld.environment.deployment.discovery.AbstractDiscoveryStrategy.performDiscovery(AbstractDiscoveryStrategy.java:124)
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.se.Weld.createDeployment(Weld.java:979)
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.se.Weld.initialize(Weld.java:796)
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.se.Weld.initialize(Weld.java:177)
    at de.ruu.lab.modules.jpms.common/de.ruu.lab.modules.jpms.common.CDITest.beforeAll(CDITest.java:29)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:727)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptLifecycleMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:128)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptBeforeAllMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:70)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeAllMethods$13(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:411)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeAllMethods(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:409)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:215)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:148)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
    Suppressed: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "jakarta.enterprise.inject.se.SeContainer.close()" because "de.ruu.lab.modules.jpms.common.CDITest.seContainer" is null
        at de.ruu.lab.modules.jpms.common/de.ruu.lab.modules.jpms.common.CDITest.afterAll(CDITest.java:36)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
        at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:727)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptLifecycleMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:128)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptAfterAllMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:118)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAfterAllMethods$15(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:439)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAfterAllMethods$16(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:437)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
        at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.forEach(Collections.java:1092)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeAfterAllMethods(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:437)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.after(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:231)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.after(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:84)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:161)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:161)
        ... 34 more
```

I prepared a minimal [reproducer](https://github.com/r-uu/sandbox-jpms-cdi.weld.git) that shows this effect. From the reproducer you can see, that in the end I also want to work with jpa (hibernate), but for now everything jpa/hibernate is commented out in the reproducer.

Comment: Stack trace shows NPE on `seContainer.close();` in the `@AfterAll`.  Do the debug logs tell you anything about the instantiation in `@BeforeAll`?

Comment: Guessing here: you may need an `--add-reads yourTestModuleName=jakarta.enterprise.inject.se` to run your tests.

Comment: The upper part of the stacktrace I posted is from ```@BeforeAll```. This behaviour also occurs if I run in a non-modular environment (no ```modules-info.java```)

Comment: I'm confused, in your answer above you indicate creating the `module-info.java` caused the symptoms. Now you say the behavior is independent of modules?  The error seems associated with reflection, which needs either the module or the necessary package to be open to reading.  If it's in a dependency you may need `--add-opens` with an `ALL_UNNAMED` target.

Comment: I saw that behaviour with, without and with an empty '''modules-info.java''' yesterday. I must admit that currently I can not reproduce it. I have a working modular reproducer under the url in the original post. Maybe it can be helpful for folks struggling with similar issues. Sorry for not being able to reproduce yesterday's behaviour.

Comment: I had a closer look and this is what I found: as kinda old school eclipse fan boy I struggled with intellij, therefore switched back to eclipse and got my project (see reproducer above) running instantly from the ide (latest version). Switching to intellij again I also see the above exception again. Running mvn test fails with the same error.

eclipse has the project itself under module path. I do not currently know how to achieve that for intellij and maven. I'll have a look into that.

Comment: I found no indication that Weld supports JPMS. A corresponding issue is still open: https://issues.redhat.com/browse/WELD-2493. Do not expect it to work with some minor tweaks until officially supported. Doing so would bring the people you are coding for most likely in trouble. The current situation indicates that you have to choose between Weld and JPMS.